# Displaying base64 encoded image inside of laravel's Email Template

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have an image i converted to base 64 encoded image. I am sending the image via email in laravel. I have tried attaching it as an inline image as well as an attachment. But as an inline image the image does not display but shows the base 64 code on the email page. As an attachment the attached image has nothing inside of it. It work well if i render in laravel's blade template view. But in laravel's email template view. It does not work. Why??

Here is my code below

In the controller:

```
$base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' .base64_encode($img_canvas);
IN THE MAILABLE CLASS
Mail::to([$email])->send(new SendPoem($yourname, $mothername, $email, $image));
public function build()
    {
return $this->from("no-reply@omo.com",'Omo')
 ->subject("Happy Mother's Day")
 ->with('yourName', $this->yourName)
 ->with('motherName', $this->motherName)
 ->with('motherEmail', $this->motherEmail)
  ->with('image', $this->image)
 ->view('emails.send-poem')
 ->attachData(base64_decode($this->image), 'poem-for-mom.png', [
 'mime' => 'image/png',
]);}
```

In the email view template:

```
<img class="adapt-img" src="{!! $image !!}"/>
```

Comment: Where's the code?

Comment: I can't seem to add it

Comment: just copy paste it into your question.

Answer (score 0):

In blade file
use the path where your image is stored.

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,{{base64_encode(file_get_contents(resource_path('imgs/logo.png')))}}" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Sending a Base64 image in a email is not supported in some of the Emails

Here is the list of popular email clients for supporting Base64 Emails

```
iOS Mail     |  Yes 
Outlook 2003 |  Yes 
Apple Mail   |  Yes 
Yahoo! Mail  |  No  
Gmail        |  No  
Android      |  Yes
```

Comment: So how then can i send one